# Python's __radd__ doesn't work for C-defined types

Tags: python, python-2.7, built-in, python-c-extension, python-extensions

When creating a python (2.7.5) extension that defines a `noddy.Noddy` type with `__radd__` method, it gets a different behavior from a (otherwise equivalent) python defined-class object with a custom `__radd__` (the former does not work, while the latter works). Example:

```
class PythonClass():
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return 'indeed!'

w = PythonClass()
d = noddy.Noddy()

print(w.__radd__)
print(d.__radd__)

print('the following works:')
print([1] + w)
print('the following does not work:')
print([1] + d)
```

And the corresponding output:

```
<bound method PythonClass.__radd__ of <__main__.PythonClass instance at 0xf6e9792c>>
<built-in method __radd__ of noddy.Noddy object at 0xf749d4b8>
the following works:
indeed!
the following does not work:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/2.py", line 44, in <module>
    print([1] + d)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "noddy.Noddy") to list
```

The method `d.__radd__` is not called, but `w.__radd__` is. Any ideas as to why this is so? The behavior of `[1] + x` where `x` is a `PythonClass` instance seems to be in accord with the [documentaton](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__), and I would expect `noddy.Noddy` to work as well. Also, both are types unrelated to `list`.

Workarounds are welcome. I've already tried patching `list.__radd__` with [forbiddenfruit](http://clarete.github.io/forbiddenfruit/), with no success, though I have brought this issue to the author's attention, who happens to be a close friend of mine.

**EDIT**

...and here is a picture of the C land:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
} Noddy;


static PyObject*
Noddy_radd(PyObject* _self, PyObject* args) {
    printf("Noddy_radd!\n");
    return NULL;
}

static PyObject*
Noddy_add(PyObject* _self, PyObject* args) {
  printf("Noddy_add\n");
  return NULL;
}

PyNumberMethods noddy_nums = {
  Noddy_add,         /* binaryfunc nb_add;         /* __add__ */
    0,               /* binaryfunc nb_subtract;    /* __sub__ */
    0,               /* binaryfunc nb_multiply;    /* __mul__ */
    0,               /* binaryfunc nb_divide;      /* __div__ */
    0,               /* binaryfunc nb_remainder;   /* __mod__ */
    0,               /* binaryfunc nb_divmod;      /* __divmod__ */
    0,               /* ternaryfunc nb_power;      /* __pow__ */
    0,               /* unaryfunc nb_negative;     /* __neg__ */
    0,               /* unaryfunc nb_positive;     /* __pos__ */
    0,               /* unaryfunc nb_absolute;     /* __abs__ */
    0,               /* inquiry nb_nonzero;        /* __nonzero__ */
    0,               /* unaryfunc nb_invert;       /* __invert__ */
    0,               /* binaryfunc nb_lshift;      /* __lshift__ */
    0,               /* binaryfunc nb_rshift;      /* __rshift__ */
    0,               /* binaryfunc nb_and;         /* __and__ */
    0,               /* binaryfunc nb_xor;         /* __xor__ */
    0,               /* binaryfunc nb_or;          /* __or__ */
    0,               /* coercion nb_coerce;        /* __coerce__ */
    0,               /* unaryfunc nb_int;          /* __int__ */
    0,               /* unaryfunc nb_long;         /* __long__ */
    0,               /* unaryfunc nb_float;        /* __float__ */
    0,               /* unaryfunc nb_oct;          /* __oct__ */
    0,               /* unaryfunc nb_hex;          /* __hex__ */
};

static PyMethodDef Noddy_methods[] = {
    {"__radd__", (PyCFunction)Noddy_radd, METH_VARARGS,
     "__radd__ function"},
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};


static PyTypeObject NoddyType = {
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
    0,                         /*ob_size*/
    "noddy.Noddy",             /*tp_name*/
    sizeof(Noddy),             /*tp_basicsize*/
    0,                         /*tp_itemsize*/
    0,                         /*tp_dealloc*/
    0,                         /*tp_print*/
    0,                         /*tp_getattr*/
    0,                         /*tp_setattr*/
    0,                         /*tp_compare*/
    0,                         /*tp_repr*/
    &noddy_nums,               /*tp_as_number*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_sequence*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_mapping*/
    0,                         /*tp_hash */
    0,                         /*tp_call*/
    0,                         /*tp_str*/
    0,                         /*tp_getattro*/
    0,                         /*tp_setattro*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_buffer*/
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT |
      Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_SEQUENCE_IN | /* tp_flags */
      Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_ITER,
    "Noddy objects",           /* tp_doc */
    0,                     /* tp_traverse */
    0,                     /* tp_clear */
    0,                     /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                     /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,                     /* tp_iter */
    0,                     /* tp_iternext */
    Noddy_methods,             /* tp_methods */
    0,                         /* tp_members */
    0,                         /* tp_getset */
    0,                         /* tp_base */
    0,                         /* tp_dict */
    0,                         /* tp_descr_get */
    0,                         /* tp_descr_set */
    0,                         /* tp_dictoffset */
    0,                         /* tp_init */
    0,                         /* tp_alloc */
    PyType_GenericNew,         /* tp_new */
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's getattr is a tricky guy. The `__radd__` method is part of the [in]famous magic methods. They're not stored in the same array as the regular methods (`ob_type->tp_methods`), it is part of the `ob_type->tp_as_number`, managed separately by the [Number Protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/number.html).

Forbidden fruit has an issue requesting the ability to monkey patch those methods. This effort is [documented here](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit/issues/4)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__), look at the [footer](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#id6).

> For operands of the same type, it is assumed that if the non-reflected method (such as **add**()) fails the operation is not supported, which is why the reflected method is not called.

Comment: I'm aware of it: type([1]) != type(d) and type([1]) != type(w). So, it doesn't really apply.

Answer (score 0):

How did you implement `__radd__`?

For C extensions, `__radd__` isn't explicitly defined. There is a single slot called `nb_add` that supports a pointer to function that accepts two arguments. In a Python class method, the first argument is always the instance (i.e. `self`). So both normal and reflected methods are required. This is not true for C extensions. `nb_add` can be called with the instance as either argument.

**EDIT**

It will probably be easier to understand if you rewrite the signature of Noddy_add as `Noddy_add(PyObject* a, PyObject* b)`. Let d be an instance of a custom C type. Then `[1] + d` is processed as follows (ignore the abuse of syntax and some special cases):

`PyNumber_Add([1], d)` is called. It first tries `ListType.nb_add([1], d)` which fails because the ListType doesn't implement `nb_add`. Then it tries `NoddyType.nb_add([1], d)` and this is the call you want to handle. If this call fails, then `ListType.sq_concat([1], d)` is called.

When you evaluate `d + [1]`, the same sequence ends with `NoddyType.nb_add(d, [1])`. `ListType.sq_concat` is not called unless you implement the sequence methods for NoddyType.

You need to modify `Noddy_add` so it can be called with a reference to a list as the first parameter and a reference to a NoddyType as the second parameter. Calling `nb_add` with the arguments reversed is equivalent to `__radd__` in Python code.

For details, see `PyNumber_Add` in Objects/abstract.c

Comment: I added the C code to the question. `nb_add` works when both operands are of the same type, however I need the operation to work with lists (ie. I need the same behavior that worked with python classes, which is also, as I gather, the same documented behavior).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! `nb_add` wasn't being called at all. It took me hours to accidentally lay my eyes on the flag `Py_TPFLAGS_CHECKTYPES` that can be used to indicate `nb_add` can be called with operands of different types. And it worked!